# Python - How to split image using PIL

Tags: python

I would like to know what is the best way to split a given image into multiple images where each image includes one object.
For example, in vase the image includes - Tree, dog, cat, ball
The output should be four different images of Tree, dog, cat, ball

BTW, I'm using PIL module in python.

Thanks

Comment: Post any code you've written to tackle this problem, please.

Comment: Guess on which side of this you are: http://xkcd.com/1425/

Answer (score 0):

In short: you can't do that.

Longer answer: this apparently simple task involves not only what would be some somewhat complicated code (15-50 lines), just to separate your original image into arbitrarily shaped parts, paste them on a default background, choosing an appropriate name and saving each part.

It involves object recognizing - just like humans do - so, it is a bit strong to say "you can't do that", but that involves A.I. techniques for image recognition, **a lot**, and I mean **a lot** of work in getting your neural-networking tool correctly coupled and trained to identify distinguished objects. (A lot like: years with a team, not hours for a person).

And anyway, even if you'd know where to start from, PIL alone does not fit that - PIL is a quick image manipulation library with a handfull of image methods. Although most of the machinery for Python A.I. image processing can use PIL to convert an image to a NumPy array representation were the "real algorithms" will be run.

Now, if you don't care that the program knows *which* objects are in the image, just that distinct objects on the image are saved to different files, one could come with a series of image processing filters to segment the image without resourcing to A.I. at all - that would be just **a lot** of work like 3 days up to two weeks for one with some experience in image processing. A couple hours if the person is with her skills really sharp and the images have a good contrast with the background  and no object superposition.